# OOP "Ready Query" In Class

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm pretty new in OOP and I'm trying to build a class that will insert lines into a table by the info I give it from the actual page, it's a bit hard to explain… This is my code:

Actual page:

```
include_once 'Classes/New_Topic.php';

$number = 1;
$shenhav = 'shenhav';
$boring = 'boring';

$New_Topic = new New_Topic();

$query_table = 'forums';
$query_values = '`Category_ID`, `Name`, `Description`';
$query_question = '?,?,?';
$bind_param_sss = 'iss';
$bind_param_date = ''.$number.','.$shenhav.','.$boring.'';

$New_Topic->db_insert($query_table, $query_values, $query_question,     $bind_param_sss, $bind_param_date);
```

Class:

```
class New_Topic
{
    function db_insert($query_table, $query_values, $query_question, $bind_param_sss, $bind_param_date) {

        $this->con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'forum');

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$query_table.' ('.$query_values.') VALUES ('.$query_question.')');
        $stmt->bind_param($bind_param_sss, $bind_param_date);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
the problem is in `$bind_param_date`, again, don't really know how to explain it but I will try.
You need the line to look like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param($bind_param_sss, $number, $shenhav, $boring);
```

with the variables. And in my code it's gonna show like that, which sadly, is not gonna work cuz some reason:

```
$stmt->bind_param($bind_param_sss, 1, shenhav, boring);
```

Hope I explained it well.

How can I fix it please?

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: someone added it for me now :)

Comment: Check here http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php You have to pass the values each as argument. If you have at least PHP 5.6, you can use arguments unpacking `bind_param($bind_param_sss, ...$bind_param_date)` and pass the values as array to the method.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois When i try to unpack it like you wrote i got an error:
"Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked"

Comment: Yeah, you have to pass the values as array, currently you make a string. `$bind_param_date = ''.$number.','.$shenhav.','.$boring.'';` => `$bind_param_date = array($number, $shenhav, $buring);`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks!!!! It works!! :D